# Missing .class files in Eclipse O2/Wildfly 10.1.0 war deployment

Tags: eclipse, maven, deployment, jboss, wildfly

I am working on a project to manage and orchestrate a legacy Wildfly Java/Maven web application. I know very little about the application itself, and frankly, not much about Wildfly. I am using Eclipse Oxygen and Wildfly 10.1.0 with the JBoss plugin.

I am following sketchy deployment instructions for the app and they're not working. However, this application has deployed for other folks on the project.

When publishing the app (I've tried clean, publish, full publish etc.), the resultant exploded war in standalone/deployment is missing .class files. However, the missing .class files are present in the taget directory and they are in the .WAR file, they're just not in the Widlfly deployment.

This application builds two base 'com' packages. Let's call them com.rrr and com.ttt for anonymity.

When the application builds, there is the expected WEB-INF/classes/com directory structure (in target and the war) with all package directories and all .class files present.

When deployed to Wildfly, all of the package directories are present for both com.rrr and com.ttt, however, **there are .class files in the com.ttt packages**, **but there are NO .class files in the com.rrr packages.**

So, when I try and deploy the app using the JBoss/Eclipse plugin, I'm getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rrr.ui.servlet.ActionServlet from [Module "deployment.myapp-18.1.0.0.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

Again, this deployment works for others (who are unavailable at this time) so I don't think it's a project issue. Perhaps I have configured something wrong based on the sketchy instructions?

Any guidance on what to look for or how to solve this would be appreciated.